# From base_laser_link to odom frame transformation?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to solve a problem related to frame transformations. I have two frames, /odom and /base_laser_link. I can calculate coordinates of obstacle from laser_scan ( base_laser_link is frame), but I'm having a problem transforming those coordinates from /base_laser_link to /odom. I need real coordinates of obstacles. I tried to use tf class, but problem is i don't know how to transform that point from one frame to another using this class.

---

Edit:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf2::InvalidArgumentException'
  what():  Invalid argument passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty
```

This is the error that I got. Anyway I'm trying to calculate coordinates of obstacle points using LaserScan msgs. I made a callback function in witch I'm calculating those coordinates and now I'm trying to recalculate them using TranformListener , so that I can get coordinates in /odom frame. I need this approach in order to exclude points from optimization problem. Template that I used for converting LaserScan msgs to 2D coordinates is as folows:

For the Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 (as an example), the angular resolution is 0.36° which is what you would get if you do 240/ranges.size().

Therefore, assuming the X axes (phi=0) is following ROS convention, you have to set -120° to ranges[0] and then increase it by 0.36°. In summary: phi = (i * 0.36)-120. And then, convert to radians.

Hope you understand the problem. And thanks for help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270474/from-base_laser_link-to-odom-frame-transformation?/) by [ANY](https://answers.ros.org/users/22379/any/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-09**:
@ANY: please don't post answers unless you are answering your own question. For the rest, please use comments or *update* your original question. Use the *edit* link/button for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the function `transformPoint` from `tf::TransformListener`.

```
tf::TransformListener listener;     

geometry_msgs::PointStamped point_in_laser_frame; // fill it with your point in base_laser_link frame
geometry_msgs::PointStamped point_in_base_frame;  

listener.transformPoint("/odom", point_in_laser_frame, point_in_base_frame);
```

---

[This tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29) will be helpful for your task.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2017-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ANY](https://answers.ros.org/users/22379/any/) on 2017-09-08**:
[C:\fakepath\eror.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15048849167111132.png)
When I used this approach, I got this error message. Any help please? I define a TransformListener object like a private attribute  of the class.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-08**:
@ANY: don't use screenshots for this. Just copy-paste console text into your comment or question. In this case, please *edit* your original question to add the update.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2017-09-09**:
@ANY, Error says  frame ids are empty. You should fill `frame_id` in `header` of `geometry_msgs::PointStamped`. Check [this](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF#Using_a_Transform)